# Flutter TextField FocusNode not gaining focus back [FocusNode "NOT FOCUSABLE"]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **TextField** with a `focusNode` that suddenly stops gaining focus after changing screens.
One thing I notice though, the object changes its value `canRequestFocus` to `false` for no reason.

FocusNode value before launching other Widget:

`FocusNode#1502a(context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#26e29])`

FocusNode value after launching other Widget and TextField doesn't get focus when I tap:

`FocusNode#1502a(context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#26e29], NOT FOCUSABLE)`

The problem doesn't happen on Android.

I've created this
[Sample Project](https://github.com/renannery/flutter_textfield_focus_issue) and this [Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17n973D3f4N1cYTPR0EzSGnWzTcMcOt5G)
showing how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You mentioned changing screens, but this is not shown in the GIF above. Is the FocusNode disposed at some point maybe? Also, does this happen on a simulator or a physical device?

Comment: You are right, I've just updated the video reproducing the steps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. It only happens when you swipe to close the second page. I end up fixing it by upgrading my Flutter from `v2.8.1` to `v2.10.1`