# Flutter - ios native swipe back disabling all TextInputs

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app which I have been developing for quite some time but only now am I noticing this bug. I push a view

`Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pushNamed(...);`

and when swiped back using the ios swipe back feature, all TextInputs on the root page are disabled, this does however, not happen when the back button is pressed on the pushed page, all the onPressed does there is simply:

`Navigator.of(context).pop();`

Has anyone encountered something similar before and/or has a solution or any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Can you add a screen recording or screenshot that show clearly what the `TextInputs on the root page are disabled` is?

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering, I found the same issue in this link. There is a video posted by the author of this question which highlights the issue. It appears that the FocusNodes inherit some sort of "NOT FOCUSABLE" attribute when swiped back. I have still not found a solution yet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60123438/flutter-textfield-focusnode-not-gaining-focus-back-focusnode-not-focusable